# SEO Audit - HTML Sitemap and XML Sitemap Difference

Tags: seo

What is the difference between html sitemap and xml sitemap in SEO?

Answer (score 0):

An XML sitemap is a tool used by search engines to crawl your site. It is in theory not always needed, but Google recommends that you always have one.

A HTML sitemap is map of your site displayed in a user friendly format, a page with links that the user can use to navigate your website. As long as you have a good XML sitemap it won't really affect your SEO.

Few sites have HTML sitemaps anymore since it's generally not the way people prefer to navigate a page, but of course this will vary from site to site. If you think the user is helped by a HTML sitemap then you should make one, but you don't need to create one for SEO reasons.

Comment: If my answer is wrong, then please leave a comment explaining how.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, HTML sitemap is userfriendly so its useful for users, and XML Sitemap is for Webmasters.

HTML Sitemap contain all pages in sequence while XML Sitemap contain in Hierarchy manners.

Answer (score 0):

HTML sitemap is more likely to assist users (people/website visitors) on the site's website directory. XML, on the other hand, assists bots or crawlers (like Google bots) to know more about the website's architecture or directory. If you are confused which one to use, I would rather select XML for the bots. HTML are not used by most users. They're more likely concerned with the navigation menu.